# how to obtain index of dataframe by comparing values of a column to a string without iterrows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe(df) with a large number of rows :

```
0   A     B     C     D     E
1   ax    92    47    32    89
2   av    12    41    26    87
3   bn    54    87    98    09
```

string='av'
I need to find the index of df with A=av
it need to return 2

I tried using `df.iterrows()`, but there are a huge number of rows which takes a lot of time or crashes

Is it possible to do this without iterrows ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use boolean filtering and `.loc`.

Three ways to access value `2` from column `'0'`

```
In [377]: df.loc[df['A'] == 'av', '0']
Out[377]:
1    2
Name: 0, dtype: int64

In [378]: df.loc[df['A'] == 'av', '0'].item()
Out[378]: 2L

In [379]: df.loc[df['A'] == 'av', '0'].iloc[0]
Out[379]: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
index=df.loc[df['A'] == 'av', '0'].iloc[0]
```

This technique is called Boolean Masking.index will have value 2
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html
Refer to Pandas Documentation. Pandas is well documented !